# Code completion doesn't work in VS Code for OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I work on **Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** and use **VS Code** for coding. Currently I am working on a project using **Python-3.6** and **OpenCV 4.1.1**, and everything was working quite well, until I needed to use the **SURF** and **SIFT** non-free algorithms in OpenCV.

These two algorithms are not included in [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) installed via pip command.

So I built OpenCV library as I needed, and it worked fine. The problem is, auto completion is not working any more for OpenCV. It shows very different codes to complete, which include the **"bootstrap()"** function and namespaces like **"load_config_py2"** and **"load_config_py3"**.

After I searched, I guess the problem is the absence of Python prototype files, since as I discovered, Python looks in the source code for its libraries to get its code completion.

All other libraries work fine, and the OpenCV code itself is running fine. The problem is just in the auto completion.

Comment: Are you using Jedi or the language server? If the former then please go to your settings and uncheck "Jedi Enabled" and see if that solves things for you.

Comment: I tried both Jedi and lang server, but they both showed the same wrong completion

Comment: Could you file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server then? That way we can have a look and try to fix the problem. You can also follow the instructions at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977 to try out the beta version of the language server.

Comment: OK I will report a bug after attempting the instructions, thank you for your contribution.